# How to change filesystem UUID (2 same UUID)?

Tags: linux, filesystems, cloning, uuid

I have a fedora guest OS in VMware. I want to expand `/boot` partition, so I add another virtual disk to this VM, and try to clone the disk.

After `dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdb1`, `blkid` report that **/dev/sda1** and **/dev/sdb1** have same UUID/GUID.

It's weird that there're 2 same UUIDs in the universe, how to change one of them to another UUID value?

---

## Update 2017-01-25

Subject changed, UUID here means filesystem UUID, not partition UUID.

Since it's filesystem UUID, filesystem specific utils are needed to change the UUID, or use hexeditor to modify raw data on disk (**DANGEROUS, not recommended unless you know what you are doing**).

Comment: It's not weird at all. When you clone a partition with dd, of course the clone will have the same UUID as the original. The UUID is just metadata of the partition - not some inherent property of a physical disk.

Comment: Thank you Andrew, I thought UUID is a calculated value before when a new partition been created. Now I know it's just a metadata stuff.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

To generate a random new UUID, one can use:

```
$ uuidgen
```

To actually change the UUID is file system dependent.

### Assuming ext-family filesystem

```
# tune2fs -U <output of uuidgen> /dev/sdb1
```

Or if you're confident uuidgen is going to work:

```
# tune2fs -U $(uuidgen) /dev/sdb1
```

### Assuming btrfs filesystem

```
# btrfstune -U $(uuidgen) /dev/sdb1
```

The UUID is stored in the superblock, so a byte-for-byte copy of the filesystem will have the same UUID.

Comment: Andy, you don't even need uuidgen command: "tune2fs -U random /dev/sdb1" should work fine

Comment: How to run it on FAT?

Comment: @CMCDragonkai, see my answer.

Comment: you can also just do `tune2fs -U random /dev/sdb1`

Comment: N.B. this does not work when you have multiple physical devices and their partitions combined within single volume.

Comment: just a head's up ... blkid may not show that the UUID has changed. This is because the value has been cached. Run sudo blkid -p <partition> to get the true value.

Answer (score 34):

Besides of ext2 /ext3 / ex4 and xfs, you can also change UUID of the following filesystem or block device or PARTUUID of GPT partition.

## Swap

`swaplabel -U $NEW_UUID`

## Software RAID (md raid)

For MD RAID, you must stop the RAID first, then update the UUID when re-assembling. So if your RAID is mounted to `/`, you can't stop it, you need update UUID in offline mode -- use a live CD/USB to do it.

1. `mdadm --stop $RAID_DEVICE`
2. `mdadm --assemble $RAID_DEVICE --update=uuid --uuid=$NEW_UUID $MEMBER_DEVICES...`

Example:

1. `mdadm --stop /dev/md127`
2. `mdadm --assemble /dev/md127 --update=uuid --uuid=2A1D2A1D-2A1D-2A1D-2A1D-2A1D2A1D2A1D  /dev/sda2 /dev/sdb2`

After UUID been updated, you may need to update `grub.cfg` (`rd.md.uuid=$NEW_UUID` in `linux/linuxefi/linux16` command line) and/or `fstab` and/or `mdadm.conf` and/or `update-initramfs` (Debian family) and/or `dracut --force` (Red Hat family) so that you can boot successfully next time.

## LUKS (cryptsetup)

`cryptsetup luksUUID --uuid=$NEW_UUID  $LUKS_DEVICE`

Example:

`cryptsetup luksUUID --uuid=e0c0e0c0-e0c0-e0c0-e0c0-e0c0e0c0e0c0 ~/encrypted-LUKS.loop`

## NTFS file system

There's `ntfslabel` utility (thanks to [ntfs-3g](http://www.ntfs-3g.org)) to change UUID of NTFS file system. See [abchk1234's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12858/how-to-change-filesystem-uuid-2-same-uuid#556144).

In case you wanna change the whole UUID of NTFS file system instead of `--new-half-serial`, use the `--new-serial` option.

Example:

`ntfslabel --new-serial=1122334455667788 /dev/sda3`

## FAT / exFAT file system

This is another story here, <del>currently there're no utilities to modify the filesystem UUID of these filesystems</del> (See [reichhart's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12858/how-to-change-filesystem-uuid-2-same-uuid#436306) -- the `mlabel` tool), but we can modify raw data on disk to do this.

**WARNING, it's dangerous to modify raw data on disk, and could lost data without careful operation.**

Here's detail steps to modify raw data on disk using `hexedit`.

1. `blkid`, write down the UUID of filesystem to paper, or remember it. The UUID string of FAT / exFAT looks like `1122-3344`, UUID string of NTFS looks like `1122334455667788`.
2. Open partition device using hexedit

   `hexedit <partition device such as /dev/sda1>`
3. Press <kbd>/</kbd>, enter the UUID in reverse order (if `blkid` reported `1234-ABCD`, then search `CDAB3412`) to search the UUID data on disk.
4. Once UUID is located, change them, press <kbd>F2</kbd> to save and exit.
5. `blkid` to verify the UUID.
6. Once UUID is modified, you may need to update `grub.cfg` and/or `fstab` so that you can boot successfully next time.
7. Execute `fsck <partition device such as /dev/sda1>` and see a *"There are differences between boot sector and its backup"* message. In order to solve it, select *"1) Copy original to backup"*, and if you are asked *"Perform changes ? (y/n)"* you press <kbd>y</kbd>.

---

## PARTUUID of GPT partition

**A short story**: I never thought I will need to touch PARTUUID of GPT partition, until now, when I try to migrate Windows from a small disk to a large disk, Windows failed to boot on the large disk and it can't even be repaired automatically. The reason is that changing UUID of NTFS file system to the original one isn't enough for Windows + UEFI, you also need to change the PARTUUID of GPT partition - PARTUUID matter. (After changed PARTUUID to the original one, Windows successfully booted from the large disk.)

There's already [an answer here on askubuntu.com](https://askubuntu.com/a/1250232/97724) to show how to change PARTUUID of GPT partition using `gdisk` utility.

The current version of `fdisk` (2.35.2 in Fedora 32 repositories at the time of editing) from util-linux can do that too in expert mode, in fact, starting from [util-linux v2.23](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table#UNIX_and_Unix-like_systems), fdisk has been GPT-enabled.

Here's an example of changing PARTUUID using util-linux `fdisk` utility:

```
# truncate -s 200M /tmp/file-as-a.disk 

# LANG=en_US.UTF-8 fdisk /tmp/file-as-a.disk 

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.35.2).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.

Device does not contain a recognized partition table.
Created a new DOS disklabel with disk identifier 0xc0fc8503.

Command (m for help): g
Created a new GPT disklabel (GUID: 4CD23B97-80C5-BD42-8466-1B9476653A92).

Command (m for help): n
Partition number (1-128, default 1): 
First sector (2048-409566, default 2048): 
Last sector, +/-sectors or +/-size{K,M,G,T,P} (2048-409566, default 409566): 

Created a new partition 1 of type 'Linux filesystem' and of size 199 MiB.

Command (m for help): i
Selected partition 1
         Device: /tmp/file-as-a.disk1
          Start: 2048
            End: 409566
        Sectors: 407519
           Size: 199M
           Type: Linux filesystem
      Type-UUID: 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4
           UUID: 7265D7C3-6277-DE4B-956C-41E3BFFF8E0D

Command (m for help): w
The partition table has been altered.
Syncing disks.

# LANG=en_US.UTF-8 fdisk /tmp/file-as-a.disk 

Welcome to fdisk (util-linux 2.35.2).
Changes will remain in memory only, until you decide to write them.
Be careful before using the write command.


Command (m for help): x

Expert command (m for help): m

Help (expert commands):

  GPT
   i   change disk GUID
   n   change partition name
   u   change partition UUID
   l   change table length
   M   enter protective/hybrid MBR

   A   toggle the legacy BIOS bootable flag
   B   toggle the no block IO protocol flag
   R   toggle the required partition flag
   S   toggle the GUID specific bits

  Generic
   p   print the partition table
   v   verify the partition table
   d   print the raw data of the first sector from the device
   D   print the raw data of the disklabel from the device
   f   fix partitions order
   m   print this menu

  Save & Exit
   q   quit without saving changes
   r   return to main menu


Expert command (m for help): u
Selected partition 1

New UUID (in 8-4-4-4-12 format): 11223344-5566-7788-9900-AABBCCDDEEFF

Partition UUID changed from 7265D7C3-6277-DE4B-956C-41E3BFFF8E0D to 11223344-5566-7788-9900-AABBCCDDEEFF.

Expert command (m for help): w
w: unknown command

Expert command (m for help): r

Command (m for help): w

The partition table has been altered.
Syncing disks.

# losetup --partscan /dev/loop101 /tmp/file-as-a.disk

# blkid /dev/loop101*
/dev/loop101: PTUUID="4cd23b97-80c5-bd42-8466-1b9476653a92" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/loop101p1: PARTUUID="11223344-5566-7788-9900-aabbccddeeff"
```

Comment: What about hfs / hfs+ or hfsplus?

Comment: You can just use `mkfs.exfat -i 01234567 /dev/partitionname` where the `mkfs.exfat`command was installed by the package *exfat-utils* on Fedora Linux. Maybe you should add that to your answer, as the hexedit variant is  quite dangerous!

Comment: @erik Thanks for the tip, but we're looking for a method to update old UUID to new UUID on existing file system or block device.

Comment: Hey @LiuYan刘研 for NTFS there is `ntfslabel` tool. https://askubuntu.com/questions/642591/unable-to-mount-external-ntfs-hdds-due-to-duplicate-uuid

Comment: For everyone looking for random UUIDs, use `gdisk`, which has this feature built-in: https://askubuntu.com/a/1250232/512299 `gdisk [...]` + `x` + `c` + `...` + `R`

Comment: gdisk/fdisk method is universal for any type of partition. gdisk is more convenient (no uuidgen needed).

Comment: Ok, it should be stressed filesystem UUID is different from partition UUID. The former is represented as UUID in `blkid` the latter is PARTUUID. Both should be changed for each partition (PARTUUID with `gdisk`, UUID with corresponding filesystem tool). Don't forget to change filesystem label after cloning the disk (partition label can stay the same).

Answer (score 28):

Use:

```
tune2fs -U random /dev/sdb1
```

if it's an **ext** filesystem, or

```
xfs_admin -U generate /dev/sdb1
```

if it's an **xfs** filesystem.

---

The reason the second partition has the same UUID is because `dd` just copies data from one file to another (`dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/dev/sdb1` = `cat /dev/sda1 > /dev/sdb1`); `dd` doesn't know what a partition is, or how to generate a UUID, so it just copied all the data as-is, including the UUID, which is stored in the filysystem superblock near the start of the partition.

---

By the way,
I also think UUID (Universally Unique IDentifier) is a weird name. It should be called PGUID (Possibly Globally Unique IDentifier), or even better, just ARLN (A Reasonably Large Number).

Comment: I have backed up one my partitions on /dev/sda6.

I get the following error:

xfs_admin -U generate /dev/sda6
ERROR: The filesystem has valuable metadata changes in a log which needs to
be replayed.  Mount the filesystem to replay the log, and unmount it before
re-running xfs_admin.  If you are unable to mount the filesystem, then use
the xfs_repair -L option to destroy the log and attempt a repair.
Note that destroying the log may cause corruption -- please attempt a mount
of the filesystem before doing this.

Comment: +1 for the dirty dirty lie that is UUID... may I also suggest UNUID for "Unfortunately, Not Unique ID"

Comment: Well, I would suggest Globally Unique IDentifier (GUID) - "Globally" as in "generally", or "in general" . Oh wait... isn't this actually its original name?...

Answer (score 9):

**Partial Answer for VFAT**

For ext* and XFS file systems, there are already fine answers. 
But for VFAT, I strongly recommend to **use [mlabel](https://www.gnu.org/software/mtools/manual/html_node/mlabel.html)**
of the [mtools](https://www.gnu.org/software/mtools/manual/mtools.html) package. 
**Using hex editors is DANGEROUS.**

Use something like this to create a new UUID:

```
echo 'drive d: file="/dev/sdb3" exclusive' >> /etc/mtools.conf
mlabel -n d:
```

The first line assigns the letter `d:` to `/dev/sdb3`
by appending to the config file `/etc/mtools.conf`,
and the second line assigns a new random UUID to the `d:` drive
using the **`-n`** option. 
Add the **`-v`** option to tell `mlabel` to display the new UUID.

You can use the **`-N serial`** option
(uppercase `N` followed by a serial number) to set the UUID
to a number of your choice in case you need a specific number,
e.g., if a boot loader or some other tool
is looking for a that serial number specifically.

Comment: If you don't mind checking for exclusive access manually (as with all the other commands described here), you could do it as a single command as `mlabel -n -i /dev/sdb3 ::`

Comment: @telcoM that does not work for me, I get the error message; 
init :: non DOS media
Cannot initialize '::'
mlabel: Cannot initialize drive

Comment: @user5359531 Please check that the device you're specifying with the `-i` option actually contains a VFAT/FAT32 filesystem. The partition type ID does not have to be a true description of the partition's contents.

Comment: why am I in awe that this actually worked?

Answer (score 6):

For XFS, use: `xfs_admin -U <uuid> <device>`

Use `xfs_admin -u <device>` to view a UUID (note lower case option to view, versus upper case option to set).  Another post on U&L pointed out the `blkid` command for viewing all or some of the UUIDs on the system.

Answer (score 2):

## BTRFS

```
sudo btrfstune -u /dev/sdaX

sudo btrfstune -U 0de6bd81-7013-49a8-bdc5-d832ed209d2c /dev/sdaX
```

Running **`btrfsck`** is recommended because changing UUID in BTRFS is not an atomic operation.

Comment: N.B. this does not work when you have multiple physical devices and their partitions combined within single volume.

Answer (score 2):

**exFAT**

If you are fine just changing the volume label, just use `exfatlabel /dev/sda1 newlabel`.

However, I didn't found a tool to easily set the UUID/VolumeSerialNumber of exFAT to a specific value and LiuYan's answer didn't work for me as it keeps you left with a wrong boot sector checksum.

Using the [exFAT spec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/fileio/exfat-specification#34-main-and-backup-boot-checksum-sub-regions) I figured out the proper way to change the UUID. Here the result in pure bashism

```sh
# set exFAT UUID to aabb-ccdd
$ dd if=/dev/sda1 of=fshead bs=512 count=24
# best keep a backup if something goes wrong
$ cp fshead fshead.bak
# set UUID in main boot sector (in reversed order (little endian))
$ echo "000064: ddccbbaa" | xxd -r - fshead
# set UUID in backup boot sector
$ echo "001864: ddccbbaa" | xxd -r - fshead
# run fsck to get the checksum
$ fsck.exfat fshead
exfatfsck 1.2.5
ERROR: invalid VBR checksum 0x276e3c6f (expected 0x2771966f).
# fix the checksum (again in reversed order (little endian))
$ python -c "print('1600: '+'6f967127 '*64)" | xxd -r -c 256 - fshead
$ python -c "print('1700: '+'6f967127 '*64)" | xxd -r -c 256 - fshead
$ python -c "print('2e00: '+'6f967127 '*64)" | xxd -r -c 256 - fshead
$ python -c "print('2f00: '+'6f967127 '*64)" | xxd -r -c 256 - fshead
# check checksum (then cancel with CTRL-C)
$ fsck.exfat fshead
exfatfsck 1.2.5
WARN: file system is larger than underlying device: 256087425024 > 12288.
^C
# checksum is ok, so lets flash it back
dd if=fshead of=/dev/sda1 bs=512 count=24
```

Answer (score 1):

To change the dd command resulting duplicated disk partion UUID/s - Use GParted.

From the GParted user interface, select drive,
select partition, unmount partition. From the 'Partition folder' choose 'NEW UUID', repeat until all dd drive duplicated partition uuid/s are marked for replacement. For bootable disks, do not replace the UEFI partition uuid.

Review the selected drive letter and partition/s - All OK ? ...

Click the 'Apply All Operations' icon on the GParted user interface.
For bootable disks, edit the /etc/fstab file UUID=string/s and mount point/s.:

Answer (score 1):

For **NTFS** check [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/642591/unable-to-mount-external-ntfs-hdds-due-to-duplicate-uuid) for details.

Summary:

```
sudo ntfslabel --new-half-serial /dev/sdXN
```

Answer (score 0):

Under Fedora 27 I found that the order of the arguments plays a crucial role ... You have to write the device first, otherwise the UUID is not changed. For example

```
tune2fs /dev/sdb1 -U random
```

Comment: That seems like unusual behavior, at least given the [oneline man page](https://linux.die.net/man/8/tune2fs)'s description showing `-U` before the `device`.

Answer (score 0):

For fat filesystems use `fatlabel` command found [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/fatlabel.8.html).

Answer (score 0):

To update UUIDs of physical/logical volumes in LVM:

```
vgimportclone /physical/volume/path
```

It should be stressed filesystem UUID is different from partition UUID. The former is represented as UUID in blkid the latter is PARTUUID. Both should be changed for each partition (PARTUUID with gdisk, UUID with corresponding filesystem tool, see the above answers). Don't forget to change filesystem label after cloning the disk (partition label can stay the same).

To check if something is not correct between cloned and original drives:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
# Supply two disk devices as arguments
d1=$1
d2=$2
vars="UUID TYPE LABEL PARTLABEL PARTUUID"
declare -A noteq
noteq=([UUID]=1 [LABEL]=1 [PARTUUID]=1)
get_ids()
{
    for v in $vars; do
        eval unset $v
    done
    eval $(blkid -oexport $1)
    for v in $vars; do
        eval ${v}_${2}=\$$v
    done
}
i=1
while true; do
    p1=${d1}p$i
    p2=${d2}p$i
    [ ! -e $p1 -o ! -e $p2 ] &&
        break
    get_ids $p1 1
    get_ids $p2 2
    for v in $vars; do
        eval v1=\$${v}_1
        eval v2=\$${v}_2
        [ -z "$v1" -a -z "$v2" ] &&
            continue
        if ((${noteq[$v]})); then
            [ "$v1" = "$v2" ] &&
                echo "$v is same in $p1, $p2: $v1"
        elif [ "$v1" != "$v2" ]; then
            echo "$v isn't same in $p1, $p2: $v1 vs $v2"
        fi
    done
    ((++i))
done
```

The example output of the above script:

```
# /tmp/x.sh /dev/md126 /dev/nvme0n1
UUID is same in /dev/md126p2, /dev/nvme0n1p2: 15D6-C410
UUID is same in /dev/md126p6, /dev/nvme0n1p6: 6bb87926-9e0c-4c84-a41b-ee76add8aa29
LABEL is same in /dev/md126p6, /dev/nvme0n1p6: vortex-storage
UUID is same in /dev/md126p7, /dev/nvme0n1p7: 0bbbc977-4f66-4bab-8212-a7fd7d7573fe
LABEL is same in /dev/md126p7, /dev/nvme0n1p7: vortex-swap
UUID is same in /dev/md126p8, /dev/nvme0n1p8: c9d776b1-f2dc-485a-8bfa-2afde7b7e276
```