# Change encrypted partition UUID

Tags: partition, dm-crypt, uuid

I'm trying to change a partition's UUID, the problem is that I'm trying to change an encrypted volume. So I can't use the usual method [described here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/12858/how-to-change-partition-uuid-2-same-uuid). Since it throws the following error:

```
tune2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sda1
Couldn't find valid filesystem superblock.
```

So let's suppose this is my `blkid`:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="adc4277c-0057-4455-a25e-94dec062571c" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="23487624-01"
/dev/sda2: UUID="9f16a55e-954b-4947-87ce-b0055c6ac953" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="23487624-02"
/dev/mapper/root: LABEL="root" UUID="6d1b1654-016b-4dc6-8330-3c242b2c538b" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/home: LABEL="home" UUID="9c48b8fe-36a6-4958-af26-d15a2a89878b" TYPE="ext4"
```

What I want to change in this example is the /dev/sda1 UUID. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Do you want to change the UUID of the filesystem, or the UUID of the encrypted volume?

Comment: As stated, the /dev/sda1 UUID

Answer (score 13, accepted):

For changing the file system UUID you have to decrypt `/dev/sda1` and then run tune2fs on the decrypted device mapper device.

`sda1` itself does not have a UUID thus it cannot be changed.

The LUKS volume within `sda1` does have a UUID (which is of limited use because you probably cannot use it for mounting), though. It can be changed with

```
cryptsetup luksUUID /dev/sda1 --uuid "$newuuid"
```

Comment: That's /dev/mapper/root but if I run tune2fs on that "device" it will not change the /dev/sda1 device

Comment: @Hacktivista Added some info.

Comment: My corresponding LUKS encrypted /dev/sda1 does have a UUID, and the encrypted FS inside has another UUID. This post is 7 years old, maybe it's that.

Comment: @LuisA.Florit I guess you have misunderstood the problem or the answer. Your comment does not even state what you think is wrong(?) with the answer.

Answer (score 4):

To change the UUID of the LUKS volume, use `cryptsetup luksUUID --uuid=<the new UUID> /dev/sda1`.