# Unable to change UUID of exFAT USB drive using tune2fs

Tags: linux, partition, usb, devices, uuid

I am trying to change the UUID of a USB stick formatted with exFAT. I double checked that `/dev/sdb2` is the correct target. The entire USB contains one exFAT partition with no empty space. When I try to give a new UUID using `tune2fs` I get an error message:

```
root@DESKTOP:/# tune2fs /dev/sdb2 -U random
/sbin/tune2fs: Bad magic number in super-block while trying to open /dev/sdb2
/dev/sdb2 contains a exfat file system
```

The partition is not corrupt, nor does it contain any corrupted files. What is wrong here?

Comment: `tune2fs` is tool for managing ext2/3/4 filesystems, not exfat, you need to use `exfatlabel` or `tune.exfat` (see the question Nikita proposed as duplicate).

Comment: The UUID of an exFAT file system isn’t its label, but its serial number; see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/578319/86440) for a recipe to change that.